# Adjust selection by week order in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to make a brief adjustment to the code below. Notice that I insert in my `daterange` to check from 14/11 (Sunday) to 15/11 (Monday), but the generated table shows Monday before Sunday. However, I would like it to be in the order of the chosen weekday, that is, Sunday first and then Monday. As it is, I believe it's in alphabetical order. How can I adjust this?

Code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-18","2021-10-18","2021-10-28","2021-10-30")),
                       Week = c("Monday", "Monday", "Sunday", "Sunday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                      br(),
                      tabPanel("",
                               sidebarLayout(
                                   sidebarPanel(
                                       uiOutput('daterange')
                                   ),
                                   mainPanel(
                                       dataTableOutput('table')
                                       
                                   )
                               ))
    ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    data <- reactive(Test)
    
    output$daterange <- renderUI({
        dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                       min   = min(data()$date1))
    })
    
    observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})
    
    wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
        WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
        WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo")
    )
    
    data_subset <- reactive({
        req(input$daterange1)
        req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
        days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
        Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
        weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
        wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
        #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
        
        weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
        meanTest1 <- data() %>%
            group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
            summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
        meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
        meanTest
    })
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
        data_subset()
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Output table**

[image]

Comment: Your input data shows the date1 date2 with date2 values '2021-10-18' for Monday and 2021-10-28 or 2021-10-30 for Sunday.  So, shouldn't Monday come before Sunday based on that date alone?

Comment: Or are you just looking at the order of weekday

Comment: @akrun, order of weekday.  In this case above, I selected to see from 14/11 (Sunday) to 15/11 (Monday), so I would have to show Sunday and then Monday.

Comment: ok, got it.  Can you check the solution posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a `match` on the `weekdays`

```
left_join(meanTest, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%      
         arrange(match(WeekP, weekdays(input$daterange1))) %>%
         select(-WeekP)
```

-server code

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))
  })
  
  observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})
  
  wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
    WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
    WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo")
  )
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
    weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
    wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
    #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
    
    weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
    meanTest1 <- data() %>%
      group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
      summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
    meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
    left_join(meanTest, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%      
         arrange(match(WeekP, weekdays(input$daterange1))) %>%
         select(-WeekP)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: How strange, for me it didn't. Did you make any other changes besides that line you inserted? I even copied your server, but it didn't change the order of the days of the week.  I will check what can be

Comment: @Antonio the only change was I used `wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]` because mine is english instead of portugese

Comment: Understood! I'll check

Comment: @Antonio Just by taking out from the shiny `Test %>% group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% arrange(match(Week, weekdays(as.Date(c("2021-11-14", "2021-11-15"))))) %>% pull(Week)#[1] "Sunday" "Monday"`

Comment: When I do this: `Test %>% group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>%      
    summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    arrange(match(Week, weekdays(as.Date(c("2021-11-14", "2021-11-15"))))) %>% 
    pull(Week)`, appears:  [1] "Monday" "Sunday"

Comment: @Antonio Can you show the values from `weekdays(as.Date(c("2021-11-14", "2021-11-15")))`

Comment: `> weekdays(as.Date(c("2021-11-14", "2021-11-15")))
[1] "domingo"       "segunda-feira"  `

Comment: @Antonio that was the issue.  So, the `match` was not working because the 'Week' was in the english format

Comment: I understand now! Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: @Antonio can you try the update i.e. I joined with your other data `wk_port2eng` ( i couldn't test it because the locale is different, but it should work for you)

Comment: @Antonio there was a typo, which I now corrected.  Can you test it now

Comment: Perfect, I will check now

Comment: It worked @akrun, thanks so much for the help!  Just one last question: I tested  your code it for a case where the `Week` in my database is `Week = c("Segunda", "Segunda", "Domingo", "Quarta","Quinta")`, so I left  `wk_port2eng <- data.frame(WeekE = c("Segunda","Terca","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sabado","Domingo"),
        WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo") )`.  However, it didn't work, it wasn't in the correct order. Do you have any idea what needs to change?

Comment: @Antonio  Do you have `WeekE` as in the example where it is in english instead of portugese.  I didn't understand this dataset where. both columns are portugese

Comment: @Antonio I guess you may have to consider changing the console to english and then do the match directly (as in my earlier soluiton) i.e. `Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "en_US.utf8")`. Also, should have WeekE in English as I couldn't test it properly

Comment: @akun, please, can you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487675/how-to-insert-one-more-day-of-the-week-condition-into-shiny, it is similar.

Comment: @Antonio When I try to run your code that you suggested as works,  I get No data available.  what was the date range you tested

Comment: 06/12 unitl 12/12. Remember that yours the `wk` is second, as your system is in English.

Comment: @Antonio Just to clarify `wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,] ; ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
    #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]`   Do you want to create a condition here to use either WeekE, WeekP or WeekJ from the new data.  The present code manually changes it by commenting out?

Comment: @Antonio also, is there any chance to have more than one format in the same data?

Comment: just to explain better: the code is working normally if I have a database with week names equal to `WeekE`. However, I have another database similar to the week names equal to `WeekJ`. So I would like to use both `WeekE` and `WeekJ` in the code. If I test for a database with week names like `WeekJ`, no range is shown, but if database has week names like `WeekE` yes.

Comment: So, If i underestand, you want a code to automatically select the WeekE or WeekJ or WeekP based on the value of Test$Week language, right

Comment: Exactly @akrun!

Comment: @Antonio please check the solution posted