# Display value with highest number in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the code below I'm generating mode value for some days of the week, more precisely Monday and Sunday. Note from the generated table (attached image), I have a one value for Sunday and two values ​​for Monday. So, I would like to make the following adjustment: whenever I get two values ​​of mode, show only the value with the highest number, in this case for Monday, it just would appear with the value 6.

**Code below:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tools)
library(DT)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-18","2021-10-18","2021-10-28","2021-10-30","2021-10-30")),
                       Week = c("Monday", "Monday", "Sunday", "Sunday","Sunday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE","FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 3, 2,3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -5L))

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                      br(),
                      tabPanel("",
                               sidebarLayout(
                                   sidebarPanel(
                                       uiOutput('daterange')
                                   ),
                                   mainPanel(
                                       dataTableOutput('table')
                                       
                                   )
                               ))
    ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    data <- reactive(Test)
    
    output$daterange <- renderUI({
        dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                       min   = min(data()$date1))
    })
    
    observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})
    
    wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
        WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
        WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo")
    )
    
    data_subset <- reactive({
        req(input$daterange1)
        req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
        days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
        Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
        weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
        wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
        #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
        weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
        y <- function(x) {
            x <- table(as.vector(x))
            names(x)[x == max(x)]}
       mode<-data()%>%
            group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week)) %>%
            summarize(time=y(time),.groups = 'drop')
        mode <- mode[mode$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
    })
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
        data_subset()
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may need to use `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr)
mode %>% 
   group_by(Week) %>%
   slice_max(n = 1, order_by = time)
```

In the code, the `server` code would be

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))
  })
  
  observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA_integer_, end = NA_integer_)})
  
  wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
    WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
    WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo")
  )
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(as.Date(input$daterange1[1]), as.Date(input$daterange1[2]), by = 'day')
    Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
    weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
    wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
    #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
    weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
    y <- function(x) {
      x <- table(as.vector(x))
      names(x)[x == max(x)]}
    mode<-data()%>%
      group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week)) %>%
      summarize(time=y(time),.groups = 'drop')
    mode <- mode[mode$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
    mode %>% 
       group_by(Week) %>% 
      slice_max(n = 1, order_by = time)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks @akrun! In this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875294/adjust-selection-by-week-order-in-shiny, It wouldn't be similar in the sense of inserting `order_by`