# How adjust order output table

Tags: r

Can tell me why the order is incorrect in my generated table below?. I filtered from 11/07 (Sunday) to 11/13 (Saturday). But as you can see, in the generated table, Saturday is getting by the second and not the last. The rest is OK, only Saturday went wrong.

```
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                      date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-18","2021-10-19","2021-10-20","2021-10-21","2021-10-22","2021-10-23","2021-10-24")),
                       Week = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
                      Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE","FDE","FDE","FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 3, 2,3,3,4)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -7L))

  wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
    WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
    WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terca-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sabado", "domingo")
  )

left_join(Test, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%      
  arrange(match(WeekP, weekdays(as.Date(c("2021-11-07", "2021-11-13"))))) %>%
 select(-WeekP)
       date1      date2      Week Category time
1 2021-11-01 2021-10-24    Sunday      FDE    4
2 2021-11-01 2021-10-23  Saturday      FDE    3
3 2021-11-01 2021-10-18    Monday      FDE    4
4 2021-11-01 2021-10-19   Tuesday      FDE    6
5 2021-11-01 2021-10-20 Wednesday      FDE    3
6 2021-11-01 2021-10-21  Thursday      FDE    2
7 2021-11-01 2021-10-22    Friday      FDE    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by the weekday using `lubridate::wday`

```r
left_join(Test, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%    
 arrange(match(WeekP, weekdays(as.Date(c("2021-11-07", "2021-11-13"))))) %>%
 arrange(lubridate::wday(date2)) %>%
 select(-WeekP)
#>        date1      date2      Week Category time
#> 1 2021-11-01 2021-10-24    Sunday      FDE    4
#> 2 2021-11-01 2021-10-18    Monday      FDE    4
#> 3 2021-11-01 2021-10-19   Tuesday      FDE    6
#> 4 2021-11-01 2021-10-20 Wednesday      FDE    3
#> 5 2021-11-01 2021-10-21  Thursday      FDE    2
#> 6 2021-11-01 2021-10-22    Friday      FDE    3
#> 7 2021-11-01 2021-10-23  Saturday      FDE    3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Allan for reply! However, for my purpose I need to specify the start ("2021-11-07) and end ("2021-11-13" ) dates

Comment: @Antonio specify them to do what? None of the dates in your data frame fall within this range

Comment: I'm using this code above in a shiny app. Then I need to use the  `daterange` to generate this table, so I specify two dates, a start and an end. In my app the table is generating, but the order is not correct, as in this question.

Comment: Please @Allan, look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875294/adjust-selection-by-week-order-in-shiny/69875970?noredirect=1#comment123518760_69875970

Comment: @Antonio in that case, why not sort by `wday` after the line where you specify the two dates. See my update.

Comment: Allan, in this way, it works for this example, however after look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877529/table-generated-by-shiny-with-incorrect-order if you can. I will accecpt your answer. Thank you very much!