# Table generated by shiny with incorrect order

Tags: r, shiny

This question is similiar to [How adjust order output table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877217/how-adjust-order-output-table)

However, for the shiny it didn't work, only if I make it out of the shiny.
Could you help me understand why the table is being generated with the wrong order? Note from the attached image that I'm showing the table from 11/07 (Sunday) to 11/13 (Saturday), but notice that the order is wrong (figure below). It would have to show the dates from Sunday to Saturday.

**Executable code below:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                      date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-18","2021-10-19","2021-10-20","2021-10-21","2021-10-22","2021-10-23","2021-10-24")),
                       Week = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
                      Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE","FDE","FDE","FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 3, 2,3,3,4)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -7L))


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                      br(),
                      tabPanel("",
                               sidebarLayout(
                                   sidebarPanel(
                                       uiOutput('daterange')
                                   ),
                                   mainPanel(
                                       dataTableOutput('table')
                                       
                                   )
                               ))
    ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min   = min(data()$date1))
  })
  
  observe({updateDateRangeInput(session,"daterange1",start = NA, end = NA)})
  
  wk_port2eng <- data.frame(
    WeekE = c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
    WeekP = c("segunda-feira", "terça-feira", "quarta-feira", "quinta-feira",  "sexta-feira", "sábado", "domingo")
  )
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
    weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
    wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
    #wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
    
    weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
    meanTest1 <- data() %>%
      group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
      summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
    meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
    left_join(meanTest, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%      
    arrange(match(WeekP, weekdays(input$daterange1))) %>%
    arrange(lubridate::wday(data()$date2))%>%
    select(-WeekP)
    
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Output table**
[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69877217/how-adjust-order-output-table) which has an answer? Please resolve the issue there, rather than posting the same question again.

Comment: This question involves shiny app.

Comment: Do you see the same incorrect behavior here if you actually use the suggestion of the accepted answer to that question? (From my perspective, the `shiny` wrapper here is a red herring.)

Comment: Yes, I used `arrange(lubridate::wday(data()$date2))`, as he suggested in the previous answer, however,  it didn't work. For this reason I asked this question using shiny, because separately it worked, but on shiyn it didn't.

Comment: Since this is otherwise a near-duplicate of your previous question, and you accepted an answer to that ... then I suggest you [edit] your question to include the code that was suggested and the errant output.

Comment: Oh I get it, I'll do it, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `match`, you need to either (a) give it every possible distinct value, or (b) know that a returned `NA` is inherently what you want/need.

In the use of

```r
arrange(match(WeekP, weekdays(input$daterange1)))
```

it is matching the values of several values again the values of *just two things*. You aren't telling it to sort based on a full sequence of things, you are telling R *"please sort this **vector** of things based on two strings"*. You are assuming that R will *infer* what those two strings are, and how to *project* that inference onto the rest of your data.

In this case, since `weekdays(input$..)` only includes two days of the week, everything else in your `match(.)` will be `NA`, which is obviously broken. Had you further debugged your code and looked at the output of *just* `match(.., weekdays(..))` (assign to some column), you would see

```r
    left_join(meanTest, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%      
      select(-WeekP) %>%
      mutate(sortcol = match(Week, weekdays(input$daterange1)))
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#   Week      Category  mean sortcol
#   <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>   <int>
# 1 Friday    FDE          3      NA
# 2 Monday    FDE          4      NA
# 3 Saturday  FDE          3       2
# 4 Sunday    FDE          4       1
# 5 Thursday  FDE          2      NA
# 6 Tuesday   FDE          6      NA
# 7 Wednesday FDE          3      NA
```

for which `arrange` will *not* magically infer your needs.

Use `seq` on your input range.

```r
    left_join(meanTest, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%      
      select(-WeekP) %>%
      mutate(sortcol = match(Week, unique(weekdays(seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = "day")))))
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#   Week      Category  mean sortcol
#   <chr>     <chr>    <dbl>   <int>
# 1 Friday    FDE          3       6
# 2 Monday    FDE          4       2
# 3 Saturday  FDE          3       7
# 4 Sunday    FDE          4       1
# 5 Thursday  FDE          2       5
# 6 Tuesday   FDE          6       3
# 7 Wednesday FDE          3       4
```

So that one reactive block should be:

```r
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    Test1 <- dplyr::filter(data(), date1 %in% days)
    weeks_inp <- unique(weekdays(days))  
    # wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekP %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in Portuguese in your notebook
    wk <- wk_port2eng[wk_port2eng$WeekE %in% weeks_inp,]  ###  if weekday is in English in your notebook
    
    weeks_ine <- wk$WeekE
    meanTest1 <- data() %>%
      group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
      summarise(mean = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
    meanTest <- meanTest1[meanTest1$Week %in% as.character(weeks_ine),]
    left_join(meanTest, wk_port2eng, by = c("Week" = "WeekE")) %>%      
      select(-WeekP) %>%
      arrange(match(Week, unique(weekdays(seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = "day")))))
  })
```

Producing:

[image]

BTW, this works fine as long as you are always summarizing by day-of-week, in which case `weekdays(.)` should always return a unique vector.